# Facebook Graph Api, From field is missing of visitors posts of a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm pretty new to Facebook API. I'm Admin for one Facebook Page. My Facebook app is in the development phase.

by using my credentials I generated long live user token and by using that, I generated permanent page access tokens.
I followed this article

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing`

I'm fetching feed of page it is returning almost all details except for "FROM" field of visitor posts, how to get these also ??. I'm using page access tokens only for fetching.